# javascript replace matches % in str.replace(/%|\$\s?|(,*)/g, '') but not in str.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)|%/g, '')

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match `\$\s*`, `,` and `%` in a string, say *$ 3,222* and *100%*.

In chrome dev tool,

If I do `+str.replace(/%|\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')`. I get the correct result `number`.

But if I do a `+str.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)|%/g, '')`, I get `NaN`.

Any reason for this peculiar behaviour?

```js
const str = "$ 32,333%"

console.log(+str.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)|%/g, ''))

console.log(+str.replace(/%|\$\s?|(,*)/g, ''))
```

Comment: Yes, there is a reason: `,*` matches an empty string. Use `,+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, How does `,*` affect a match on `%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/\$\s?|(,*)|%/g` is not doing what you need because `,*` is used as a non-final alternative in the alternative list. The problem arises due to how JS regex engine handles empty matches during replacement:

- In `100%`, start of string position is found with `,*`, and is replaced with ann empty string, and *the regex index is moved to the position before the next char*. The `%` alternative is not tried since `,*` "wins" and the regex "calls it a day" there
- The next steps are the same: the empty position before `0`, then before the next `0`, and `%` are matched with `,*`, and each time the regex index is moved on.

Use `,+` instead. It will no longer match empty strings. The rule of thumb is: do not use empty matching patterns in replace method if you are not sure what you are doing.

```js
var str = "$ 32,333%"
console.log(+str.replace(/\$\s?|,+|%/g, ''))
console.log(+str.replace(/%|\$\s?|,+/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question (@Wiktor's answer does a good job with that), but it seems to me your goal is to get all the digits out of the string and toss the rest. An easier alternative is to use a negative character class to match for anything that is not a digit:

```
var str = "$ 32,333%";
var num = +str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
console.log(num); // 32333
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = "$ 32,333%"
console.log(+str.replace(/\D/g, ''))
```

**\D :** means anything except digits